# Prevent error page action executing directly from a request

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core

In asp.net-core we can show user-friendly error pages by adding the StatusCodePages middleware to the pipeine. In `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     // code ...
     app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
     app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");         
     // code ...
}
```

With above code, when an unhandled exception occurs or a requested resource can not be found, the responses is handled by redirecting to `/error/{0}`. Framework correctly invokes this action

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{            
     [HttpGet("{statusCode}")]
     public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
     {           
         Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
         return View("Error", statusCode);
     }
}
```

The problem starts when client directly requests something like `~/error/{int}`. For example `www.example.com/error/500` or `www.example.com/error/400`

In these cases again the above action is being invoked (from MVC not StatusCodePages middleware) and client gets a 500 and a 400 response. In my opinion, 404 status code must be returned for all `~/error/{int}` requests.

Is there any solution, when client makes a `~/error/{int}` request to prevent MVC middleware from invoking the error action?

Comment: Try adding a 'constraint' to the standard MVC route controller to bypass 'error' controller. Another possibility might be to make the error controller accessible only to an internal process - not a user.

Comment: Why do you care if the user does make a direct request to ~/error/500?

Comment: @SRQCoder if I use route constraint then I do not get the error page at all. I am not sure how to implement your second suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()` to check whether an error has occurred. If one hasn't, then return a 404. Here is an example.

ErrorController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
    {
        var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (feature == null || feature.Error == null)
        {
            var obj = new { message = "Hey. What are you doing here?"};
            return new HttpNotFoundObjectResult(obj);
        }

        return View("Error", statusCode);
    }
}
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html) (emphasis added),

> The HttpContext type... provides an interface for getting and setting these features... **Use the pattern shown above for feature detection** from middleware or **within your application.** Calls made to GetFeature will return an instance if the feature is supported, or null otherwise.