# Asp.net Core MVC UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects localhost redirect too many times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Not sure if I am missing something obvious, or if this could be a bug.

In startup.cs, method Configure, I have  `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects'. I ended up putting a static file, hoping it would make a difference. Before I used the error method in Home controller, but the end result was identical.

Here is my Configure method in full:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/errors/{0}.html");
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I have an `error`directory, with a single static 404.html file.

if I create on purpose a 404 error, typing "joe" for example after "Home" in the URL, I get

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
```

Checking with F12/Network in Edge, I see it is redirected to the proper page, but way too many times.

So, I guess my question is: how do I change the response code once the proper error page has been hit? But I feel I should not have to do this.

Thanks in advance for helping me to understand what is happening here.

By the way, if I simply put `app.UseStatusCodePages();` it does work, but that is pretty ugly....

Comment: Is the directory `error` or `errors` like the code has it?

Comment: "I have an error directory, with a single static 404.html file." Is this directory inside wwroot?

Comment: the directory is errors, but IS NOT inside wwwroot! let me change this right now and see if it fixes it.

Comment: thats the problem, StaticFiles middleware tries to find there, and throws 404 again

Comment: OK, it DOES work, moving directory and file inside wwwroot. I would prefer to use controller and views, but as the default exception handler uses already Home/Error, I guess I will have to write my own to handle those pages errors.

Comment: @BernardG you can see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556917/prevent-error-page-action-executing-directly-from-a-request)

Comment: @tmg. Yes, I saw, but I am using Redirects, not ReExecute.

Answer (score 2):

Following what is said in this web-site:

https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/

you must put inside your Startup.cs->Configure must put this:

```
        // Will give error status code
        //app.UseStatusCodePages();
        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
```

Then you must put the following code inside you Home Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
    {
        if (statusCode.HasValue)
        {
            if (statusCode == 404 || statusCode == 500)
            {
                var viewName = statusCode.ToString();
                return View(viewName);
            }
        }

        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

And finally you will add 2 new Views to your Views->Home folder, the 404.cshtml and 500.cshtml

Where inside of 404.cshtml you can put something like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Not Found" ;    
}
<h1>(404) Page Not Found.</h1>
<p>This page doesn't exist.</p>
<p>Please, contact the support by emailing them this page error.</p>
<p>To find the available contacts go to: @Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contact", "Home")</p>
```

Inside of 500.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "(500) An Error Occurred";
}
<h1>(500) An Error Occurred.</h1>
<p>Something went wrong.</p>
<p>Please, contact the support by emailing them this page error.</p>
<p>To find the available contacts go to: @Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contact", "Home")</p>
```

Any other error executes the default Error.cshtml template (i'm using the Microsoft default Error.cshtml).