In ASP.NET Core, how can I redirect a user to a specific page on 401 or 403 errors (using razor pages)?
I've got Authorize attributes on my razor pages:
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

And I've tried both of the below in Program.cs:
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
    }
});


app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
    }
});

I placed a breakpoint on the status code checks and I noticed they are hit when loading the home page, but when I navigate to any other page they aren't hit, no check is performed and while a 403 is returned, no redirection occurs and the user gets the browser's default message about receiving a 403.
What am I missing to make the redirection occur?
-- EDIT
I also tried:
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Unauthorized");
I also tried a custom authorization handler:
public class RedirectAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public RedirectAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        if (!context.HasSucceeded)
        {
            if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden ||
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
                context.Fail();
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Interestingly, httpContext.Response.StatusCode is always 200.
Then I tried a custom middleware:
public class RedirectUnauthorizedMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RedirectUnauthorizedMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
        }
        else if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}

And placed it after UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectUnauthorizedMiddleware>();
This has the same problem as the other app.UseXXX methods. They never actually execute when an Authorize attribute fails. I've set breakpoints and they're never hit beyond loading the home page.
Which leaves me with the only thing that actually works, but unfortunately sucks:
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        if(!UserRoleList.Contains("Admin"))
        {
            return Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
        }
        // Do stuff
        return new StatusCodeResult(200);
    }


Maybe check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#exception-handler-page  or check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659651/asp-net-core-mvc-usestatuscodepageswithredirects-localhost-redirect-too-many-tim (beware of infinite loop when using that statuscode middleware though... )

make sure you have placed custom middleware before app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints() but after app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization().  could you just use this code `app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
{
    response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
}

});` . make sure you have error page is available at the specified location

@JalpaPanchal Rearranging the order to UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, UseStatusCodePages and then UseRouting causes an exception to be thrown which states: InvalidOperationException: Endpoint /Admin/UserManagement/ManageUsers contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization. Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() in the application startup code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseAuthorization() must go between them.

use the order like to avoid the error : 1. app.UseRouting()
2. app.UseAuthentication()
3. app.UseAuthorization()
4. Custom status code handling middleware (app.UseStatusCodePages)
5. app.UseEndpoints()

@JalpaPanchal That order gets rid of the error, but doesn't result in any redirection.

You can use app.UseStatusCodePages to handle HTTP status codes and context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Forbidden") context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Unauthorized") for 403 & 401 respectively.

You probably already know that it is best practice to not use Redirects in case of errors. Not in your own code, also not using a built-in feature. The best way IMHO would be to use the ...WithReExecute variant because it does not change the URL, so the user (or the search engine) will know WHICH page they could not access. Also a Redirect hides the actual 4XX result which is bad. I'd suggest comparing your code with everything that is shown here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors. And finally, make sure you are on the latest version of all packages + frameworks.

StatusCodePagesMiddleware source: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/ea27a4e56c12a08423d3b2b296b73cbbfa2063ab/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs#L46. If you are saying that the response code is always 200, it's never going to hit. Either that or your code somewhere is disabling the middleware. Would you be able to share your Program.cs code?

I got it working. The problem was where in sequence to put UseStatusCodePages. Despite the suggestions found above and elsewhere online, UseStatusCodePages actually has to be one of the first items specified.
Here's the order that got things working for me:
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    switch(response.StatusCode)
    {
        case (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
        case (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
            break;
    }
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


When you respond like this:
return Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");

Actually, you are sending HTTP Status code 307 or 308 (this is Redirect) with a payload to URI /Error/Unauthorized and then client's browser opened this page, he obtain 200 Code. Because the page was loaded successfully.
If you really want to give the client, for example, a 403 code, then you need to do the following:
return Forbid();

More info.
But in general, a variety of HTTP response codes is more suitable for web service APIs. On regular sites, it is more clearly to the user to simply show an error message. After all, the average user doesn’t care what the HTTP code was returned. Perhaps he doesn't even know what it is.

You could try this below code:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Unauthorized";
    });


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(); // Add authorization services

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//app.UseUnauthorizedMiddleware(); // Add the custom middleware after UseAuthorization


app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

output:

